# update all array elements 's property in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongo document schema like this

```
{
_id:'xxxxxx',
vip:[
    {paid:false,id:'xxxxxx',uid:'xxxxxx',time:ISODate("2019-07-30T06:32:45.666Z")},
    {paid:false,id:'xxxxxx',uid:'xxxxxx',time:ISODate("2019-07-30T07:32:45.666Z")},
    {paid:false,id:'xxxxxx',uid:'xxxxxx',time:ISODate("2019-07-30T08:32:45.666Z")},
 ]
```

}

I want to update one document's 'vip' array, in the array if the element 's property 'paid' is false, then mark this element as true.

```
const query = {'_id':_id,'vip': { '$elemMatch':{paid:false}  }}; 
let update = {};
update=   { '$set': { 'referral.vip.$.paid':true }};
collection.updateOne(query,update,{new:true});
```

the code above is working but the problem is it only update the first 'false' element to be 'true', the rest 'false' elements are not updated.

How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array update operator i.e **positional operator**.

> $[]

It indicates to modify all elements.

Try this :

> { '$set': { 'referral.vip.$[].paid':true }};

You can refer this document : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/